# ArrayList over writes all previously stored values android

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist

I am trying to calculate distance between a location(source location marker) to the other locations stored in an ArrayList(returned from  RoutesData) and storing the locations along the distances in another ArrayList. But as I add a location and its distance from source loacation in that array it overrides all previously stored locations and distances with the newly added location and distance.My code for the particular logic is.

**Class RoutesData :** returns the LatLngs to measure distance

```
public class RoutesData {



    public ArrayList<LatLng> allRoutesMainStops(){
        ArrayList<LatLng> allPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(Arrays.asList(
                //icPoints
                new LatLng(33.582752, 73.044503),new LatLng(33.595504, 73.050912),
                //station
                new LatLng(33.601097, 73.047798),new LatLng(33.598755, 73.055607),new LatLng(33.599970, 73.063225),new LatLng(33.602757, 73.066996),new LatLng(33.604297, 73.075843),new LatLng(33.608692, 73.082024),
                //ali nawaz
                new LatLng(33.617330, 73.081743),
                //centre hosp
                new LatLng(33.630072, 73.071996),new LatLng(33.631454, 73.072416),new LatLng(33.633905, 73.062379),new LatLng(33.641462, 73.063376),new LatLng(33.646714, 73.064095),new LatLng(33.651782, 73.064535),new LatLng(33.661329, 73.063974),new LatLng(33.672490, 73.055906),new LatLng(33.683642, 73.047215),new LatLng(33.689706, 73.030363),new LatLng(33.680982, 73.018654),new LatLng(33.671293, 73.016894),
                //gpo 1
                new LatLng(33.595215, 73.051496),new LatLng(33.593119, 73.054184),new LatLng(33.585280, 73.066763),new LatLng(33.588925, 73.076172),new LatLng(33.599117, 73.080001),new LatLng(33.607101, 73.083641),new LatLng(33.626583, 73.075027),
                //new LatLng(33.630072, 73.071996), //duplicate center
                new LatLng(33.631550, 73.072534),new LatLng(33.639063, 73.075742),new LatLng(33.643424, 73.077372),new LatLng(33.650480, 73.080152),new LatLng(33.663188, 73.085446),new LatLng(33.696970, 73.062966),new LatLng(33.699527, 73.073920),new LatLng(33.704257, 73.082993),new LatLng(33.707380, 73.088906),new LatLng(33.717143, 73.082961), new LatLng(33.718617, 73.084589), new LatLng(33.720660, 73.083891), new LatLng(33.727328, 73.073823), new LatLng(33.720397, 73.058392), new LatLng(33.733174, 73.087104)

                ));
        return allPoints;
    }

}
```

**Class LocationDistances:** binds location with distance.

```
public class LocationDistances {
    LatLng locs;
    double distances;
}
```

**getOverAllRoute() method in MainActivity:** which compares source Location with all the LatLngs returned from RouteData Class and Store them in a list srcLocDisList . All the trouble I am facing is in the *First loop* which is calculating distances and then adding distances and location to the srcDistList but when ever a new object is added it overwrites all previous objects with the newly added object.

```
public void getOverAllRoute(){
        //to get main route points to measure distance from
        RoutesData rD = new RoutesData();
        ArrayList<LatLng> mainRoutePoints = rD.allRoutesMainStops();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Size: "+mainRoutePoints.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //to store location + distances from source
        LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances(); 
        ArrayList<LocationDistances> srcLocDisList = new ArrayList();
        //showMarkerslongLat();
        //create source Location
        Location srcLoc = new Location("");
        srcLoc.setLatitude(sll.latitude);
        srcLoc.setLongitude(sll.longitude);

        // to compare distances from source location
        Location mainPointsLoc = new Location("");
        for(int i =0;i<mainRoutePoints.size();i++){

            mainPointsLoc.setLatitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).latitude);
            mainPointsLoc.setLongitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).longitude);
            //store distances and location in arraylist
            srcLocDis.locs = mainRoutePoints.get(i);
            srcLocDis.distances = srcLoc.distanceTo(mainPointsLoc);



            srcLocDisList.add(srcLocDis);
            Log.d("Location data: ",srcLocDis.locs.toString());
            Log.d("Saved Data: ",srcLocDisList.get(i).toString());

        }
        //Toast.makeText(this,"items1: "+srcLocDisList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationDistances min=null;
        for(LocationDistances x:srcLocDisList){
            String srcLocDisLocFile = x.locs.latitude+" "+x.locs.longitude+" distances:"+x.distances;


            min=(min==null||x.distances<min.distances)?x:min;
            Log.d("LocDist:",Double.toString(x.distances));

        }
        LatLng srcStartMin=min.locs;
        Toast.makeText(this,srcStartMin.latitude+" "+srcStartMin.longitude+" Distance"+Double.toString(min.distances), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Your code creates a new array. And then happens what?

Comment: sorry @Alex i have edited my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances();` inside the loop otherwise you're always changing the same object.

```
for(int i =0;i<mainRoutePoints.size();i++){ 
  LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances();
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks the solution worked for me but now facing another problem in the second loop after one iteration, where i checks for the minimum distance value in the list and select that object from the ArrayList ,my app crashes and while debugging it gives error "Source not found."?

Comment: yup i did so waiting for the response. thanx